# Powershell cursor

Tags: powershell, cursor

I am new to this and it is a minor issue. In powershell, after scrolling, if the list is very long,it could be nice to just hit enter and be at the cursor again. But in my version, after hitting enter, it just stays and the mousewheel needs to be activated to come down and find the cursor againg, which does not appear at the bottom. For some reason powershell really fills a lot of empty space in when listing something, so do not aim for the bottom.

Comment: Which version? What happens if you press the left arrow key?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio  My version is 5.1.19041.1682 and hitting left arrow key works great. Thanks. This leads to a 2 questions. How to move the promp without the mouse and arrow keys, like in Linux terminal.  And what should i google to find these shortcuts for powerpoint, like left arrow key you just told me?

Comment: I don't understand the questions: move the prompt? What about PowerPoint?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Sorry, not powerpoint, but powershell.  In Linux terminal, it is possible to do editing of a command. If you have to write the same long command again and just change a keyword, you will do ctrl+p to get former command. Then you will do alt+b to move the cursor backwards, and alt+f to move forward, etc. There are a lot of command shortcuts if you do not want to lift the hands off the keyboard, like in Vim.

Comment: In powershell, you press the up arrow to get the last command. While typing a command, you can press Tab to cycle through commands that start with the characters you typed. You can install Az.Tools.Predictor module to predict the command you want to type. See https://www.sans.org/blog/keyboard-shortcuts-boss/ , https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-tools-blog/announcing-general-availability-of-az-tools-predictor/ba-p/3297956 and https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2021/02/az-predictor-module-azure-powershell-predictions/

Comment: If you enter 'Help About_Line_Editing' you will get a brief description of several line editing characters, including left arrow.  If you enter 'Help About', you will get a list of all the help topics that begin with 'About'.  Most conceptual topics begin with 'About'.  If you just enter Help, you'll get an introduction to the help system.  It takes some getting used to, but help is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to simply need to press <kbd>←</kbd> (left arrow key). It will take you to the position where the cursor is/was. The right arrow key can also work but only if a cmdlet is written.